# Simplify the if logic in precondition check

Tags: java, logic

I know I can improvise this little bit (eliminate explicit throw) by using Preconditions class from Guava or by extracting method `isValidDayOfWeek()`. But that is not what I am looking for. Is there a way to simplify this logic without using the switch statement? This check is making sure that `startDayOfWeek` is one of the 7 values of the week.

```
public static TimeSlice getPreviousWeek(Date referenceDate, int startDayOfWeek)
{
  if (!((startDayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) || (startDayOfWeek == Calendar.MONDAY) || (startDayOfWeek == Calendar.TUESDAY)
                || (startDayOfWeek == Calendar.WEDNESDAY) || (startDayOfWeek == Calendar.THURSDAY)
                || (startDayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) || (startDayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY)))
  {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("getPreviousWeek(): invalid startDayOfWeek:" + startDayOfWeek);
  }
}
```

Comment: What you want is something like `startDayOfWeek IS IN {Calendar.SUNDAY ... Calendar.SATURDAY}`.  Unfortunately, Java doesn't implement primitive sets.

Comment: You can, of course, note that the days of the week are [documented in the Calendar writeup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SATURDAY) as having values 1..7 and just check bounds of >= SUNDAY and <= SATURDAY, but that's getting a hair too dependent on implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of those days of the week are guaranteed and [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY), with SUNDAY==1 and SATURDAY==7 so you just want:

```
if (startDayOfWeek < Calendar.SUNDAY || startDayOfWeek > Calendar.SATURDAY)
{
    throw ...;
}
```

If you wanted to make it crystal clear, you could always use:

```
private static final Set<Integer> VALID_DAYS = ImmutableSet.of(
    Calendar.SUNDAY, Calendar.MONDAY, Calendar.TUESDAY,
    Calendar.WEDNESDAY, Calendar.THURSDAY, Calendar.FRIDAY,
    Calendar.SATURDAY);

public static TimeSlice getPreviousWeek(Date referenceDate, int startDayOfWeek)
{
    if (!VALID_DAYS.contains(startDayOfWeek))
    {
        throw ...
    }
}
```

(That's using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`ImmutableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html), but you could use something else if you want.)

Comment: I thought of VALID_DAYS option but didn't want to go that route. unnecessary dependency on guava for simple thing

Comment: @Pangea: You could just `HashSet` if you wanted - but personally I'd immediately add a Guava dependency as a "no-brainer, it's not worth developing in Java without Guava" decision :) I'd also start using Joda Time for all your date/time stuff instead of java.util.Calendar...

Comment: I have the guava dependency on the application as a whole (from 2 years i guess) but doesn't want it on this component.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if ((startDayOfWeek < Calendar.SUNDAY) || (startDayOfWeek > Calendar.SATURDAY))
```